# Json result removes .00 when displaying in UI

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

This is how my UI looks like

[image: My Rendered Output]

My aspx page returns the following json data on ajax call

```
{
    "List": {
        "Table": [
            {
            "ID": 119,
            "ProjectName": "Date Testing",
            "ProjectDesc": "",
            "Owner": 22,
            "Colaborators": 22,
            "Priority": 3,
            "Status": 7,
            "BeginDate": "\/Date(1312137000000+0530)\/",
            "EndDate": "\/Date(1316543400000+0530)\/",
            "Budget": 105.90,
            "BudgetInDay": 30.80,
            "BudgetResource": ""}
        ],
        "Table1": [
            {
            "Tasks": 10}
        ],
        "Table2": [
            {
            "BudgetInDay": 30.80,
            "TotalTaskCostInDay": 11.00,
            "BalanceOfDays": 19.80,
            "Budget": 105.90,
            "TotalTaskCost": 75.00,
            "Balance": 30.90}
        ]
    }
}
```

Now problem is that in **Table2** object there is  two field **"BudgetInDay", and     "TotalTaskCostInDay"** having decimal values. When I displaying both **"BudgetInDay"** shows correct with precision but in case **"TotalTaskCostInDay"** precision vale is truncate because the precision value is .00.

Comment: Can you describe how you are populating this table? Show us some of that code?

Comment: how are you displaying that output in your html. show that script also.

Comment: The problem is in outputting the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format the floating point values, using the toFixed method.

```
alert( yourObject.List.Table2.Budget.toFixed(2) );
```

http://www.pageresource.com/jscript/j_a_03.htm

If you apply that to the other values to, 19.80 will be displayed as 19.80 and not 19.8.

Answer (score 4):

Your values are not strings, but integers. As far as the javascript engine is concerned, `75 == 75.00`.

Javascript has a function called `toFixed` that adds the specified precision, and converts it to a string.

```
var TotalTaskCost = 75.00; // or 75, or 75.00000. It's all the same
TotalTaskCost = TotalTaskCost.toFixed(2);

console.log(TotalTaskCost); // Logs 75.00
```

Comment: Joseph Silber: thanks for your quick response. Your answer solve my problem.